# How to make a flexible 2x3 grid using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I'm trying to create a HTML page that has 3 rows of 2 cells in each.  I want all 6 cells to fill the entire page equally without having to specify a height so that when the browser is re-sized, so to are the cells.

I am trying to use the following flex layout but I'm getting them all in a row.

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.row {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1.0;
  flex-grow: 1.0;
}

.item {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: .5;
  flex-grow: 0.5;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `outer` wrapper a *column flexbox*:

- add `flex: 1` to each `row` so that the rows share the vertical space,
- add `flex: 1` to each `item` so that the columns share the horizontal space,
- finished up with `height: 100%` on both `body` and `html` elements (you can also use *viewport height* to set the `min-height`) and setting default `body` margin to zero.

See demo below:

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column; /* added */
}

.row {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1; /* added */
}

.item {
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1; /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```